# How to create a Code::Blocks project from the cmake file?

Tags: makefile, cmake, codeblocks

I would like to use the Code::Blocks IDE to build a C++ project based on a `CMakeLists.txt` file. Previously, I was using Qt Creator, where I could open a `CMakeLists.txt` file directly, which would create a project. I could then define the build commands, eg. `cmake ../src` followed by `make -j8`. This would run `cmake` on the `CMakeLists.txt` file, and then run `make` on the `makefile`.

How can I do something similar in Code::Blocks? If I try to create a new project, it gives me the option of creating an empty project, but then I am stuck as to where to go next...

Answer (score 15):

It's similar but you have to specify the compiler, supposing that you have a folder project/build and project/src and your CMakeLists.txt is under /project. Then your commands should be something as the following :

```
$ cd build/
$ cmake .. -G"CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles"
```

you will have your CodeBlocks project created on the /build.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to be able to do this within the IDE, rather than using the command line. For example, I would like to be able to click on `Build` from the menu, and for Code::Blocks to then run `cmake ../src` followed by `make`...

Comment: @Karnivaurus Have you found a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Code::Blocks, has its own .cbp files which do the same things as Makefile automatically.

Therefore Code::blocks canot generate a Makefile, but you can build your project from an alredy existing Makefile, i've found a very good explaination of it on the [code::blocks wiki](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Code::Blocks_and_Makefiles). I do hope this will help you :)

Comment: won't help if the page doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok so after some tests it apears that the page have some sort of issues, if it doesn't load and give "502 Bad Gateway" you can try again, it will work out eventually. But the page does exist, if you search "codeblock wiki makefile" it's like one of the first results