# How to configure DLib Library with CodeBlocks?

Tags: codeblocks, dlib

I am want to study Machine Learning using DLib library with  CodeBlocks, but I am having trouble with configuring DLib with Codeblocks. Can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: dlib is designed to use CMake as build system. here are some details on using CMake with CodeBlocks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618040/codeblocks-with-cmake