# Using cmake with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, cmake, codeblocks

I have just started using Code::Blocks for editing C++ code, having used Qt Creator up until now. I want to be able to edit and compile some existing code, which comes with a CMakeLists.txt file. How can I do this?

With Qt Creator, you could specify a script which would be run when "Build" was clicked from the menu. For example, you might specify "cmake ../src", and then "make". Is there a way to do this using Code::Blocks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code::Blocks with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618040/codeblocks-with-cmake)

Answer (score 6):

You can use CMake to create a Code::Blocks project for you:

```
cmake -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" ../src
```

This will produce a `cbp` project file, which you can just open with Code::Blocks. What to do when clicking on "Compile", "Run", and so on, will have been set automatically by CMake.

Comment: can't we do this within IDE?